# How to set up a macro to open my visual basic user form?

Tags: vba

So basically I want to have a button on my first page and then the user will click this button and have the userform I created be displayed.

I am able to open visual basic through `Application.SendKeys("F11")`. But I can not run my userform from here? Any help would be great.

<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't work because the userform isn't selected. And I don't know how to select that userform inside VBA with a macro. I tried doing `Application.SendKeys("Down")`, in the hopes I can go down to that userform and select it with `Application.SendKeys("Enter")`, but that moves my active cell down inside the excel not the VBA. Thank you!

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) link.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Application.SendKeys("F11")` it's not a good idea to give your user access to the VBA interface, instead use this line to open the Userform from the press of the button:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Assuming your Userform is named "UserForm1".

And if you want your user to be able to click outside of the userform when it is open use this line instead:

```
UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers provided before are correct and I just want to add the following as an additional clarification:

Steps to display the userform.

1. Add a Command Button (ActiveX Controls) button anywhere in your excel file so that users can click on it and get the userform.
2. In VBA add a code like the following code lines inside the CommandButton added in step 1.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub